# C++ language feature: double square brackets [[ ]] used in class or method declaration

Tags: c++, attributes

I am currently diving into smart contract development for eosio. By walking through the tutorials I noticed a certain C++ language feature I have never seen before:

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract]] hello : public contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      [[eosio::action]]
      void hi( name user ) {
         print( "Hello, ", user);
      }
};
```

My question is what does the `[[eosio::contract]]` in the class declaration and the `[[eosio::action]]` in the method declaration mean? What is the term for this C++ language feature?

Comment: These are [attributes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes). Maybe someone else has more knowledge than me and can give better explanation than just posting the link to the reference :)

Comment: Thank you so much I found it. Gosh I was googling for an hour or so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the term for this C++ language feature?

The double square brackets are syntax for attributes. They are specified in the C++ standard section [dcl.attr]:

> [dcl.attr]
>
> Attributes specify additional information for various source constructs such as types, variables, names, blocks, or translation units.

---

> My question is what does the [[eosio::contract]] in the class declaration and the [[eosio::action]] in the method declaration mean?

`eosio` is a non-standard attribute-namespace, so you should consult their documentation for the meaning of their custom attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just couldn't find it. Here is the link to the corresponding reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes